# Writing formula in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, formatting

How can I write the formula shown below? I am new to LaTeX and I found how to write upper bounds but it is getting really complicated writing it as a whole.

[image]

Comment: `\{X(t)\}_{t\geq0}^{\infty}` (inside of math mode, of course)

Comment: I inserted \usepackage{mathtools} but I am getting an error mathtools.sty not found.

Comment: you must have a very minimal installation, if you don't have mathtools, you should be able to add it with the texlive or miktex package manager (whichever you are using) but you do not need mathtools here so just don't add that line.

Comment: I removed it and it worked! :) However, I am having a problem with this error saying that it do not have .sty files. I am using TexMaker and Texworks how can I install these .sty files please? Thanks!

Comment: Which distribution do you use?

Comment: what do you mean by distribution?

Comment: Both the OS and TeX Live or MiKTeX (on windows).

Comment: Windows 7, I don't use Tex Live or MiKTeX, I am using Texmaker and Texworks

Comment: The fact that you are using Texmaker and TeXworks has got nothing to do with things; these two programs are editors.

Comment: I need to install something else then?

Comment: Yes. Either [TeX Live](https://www.tug.org/texlive/) or [MiKTeX](http://miktex.org/). (Btw. if you find the answer acceptable, you should consider [accepting it](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent In inline mode you get ``$\{X(t)\}_{t \geq 0}^{\infty}$'' and in display mode you get
\begin{equation}
  \{X(t)\}_{t \geq 0}^{\infty}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Funny, from what I can see on my phone TeX.SE is highlighting that as the wrong language!